# Can't get breakpoints on XmlHttpRequest module working (Javascript engine/XHR requests)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, breakpoints, chromium, v8

IMPORTANT: Please do not give answers related to setting Javascript breakpoints in Google Chrome's DevTools debugger.  I am trying to get breakpoints working in the C++ source code for the Chromium open source browser, not within the DevTools debugger.

I'm trying to get breakpoints working in the following module so I can't trap XHR requests made by Javascript code running in a page hosted by Chromium:

C:\Users\realsensible\Documents\chromium\src\third_party\WebKit\Source\core\xmlhttprequest

I set breakpoints on nearly every salient method in that module, but they are never hit.  PhistucK pointed out that Chrome launches several processes and that it is very possible that the process executing the Javascript engine is not the same process as the main process that VS launched, thereby defeating breakpoints.

To try and test this, I launched Chrome.exe outside of VS.  I then attempted to attach to every "chrome" process that I saw in the VS Attach to Process list box (I double-checked this process list by also listing the "chrome" processes in the Task Manager).  There were 5 processes named "chrome"; the "main" chrome process and four child processes it launched.  For each process I:

1) Attached to one of the chrome processes from VS with my breakpoints active on nearly all of the significant XmlHttpRequest methods.
2) (Re) loaded a web page that I know makes many XHR requests from Javascript.
3) Detached from the process

In all 5 trials **none** of the breakpoints were ever hit.

Note, I have set breakpoints on other modules in the project that are not related to the Javascript engine, and they **do** work.  Apparently it's just the Javascript related code that I can't get breakpoints to trigger on.

Does anyone know how to get breakpoints working for the Javascript engine in Chromium?

Comment: What do you mean by "breakpoints"? Do you edit the chromium source files while an instance of chromium is running? _"To try and test this, I launched Chrome.exe"_ Is the question relevant to chromium or chrome? Why is question tagged `chromium` if you are launching "Chrome.exe"? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note Chrome and Chromium are two different browsers [What Is The Difference Between Google Chrome And Chromium Browser?](https://fossbytes.com/difference-google-chrome-vs-chromium-browser/)

Comment: @guest271314 - I am using the source code for the Chromium open source browser found at this location:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code

I set breakpoints within the source code and I have not changed the source code.  The default executable name for the browser project within the monolithic solution for Chromium is chrome.exe.

Comment: _"I set breakpoints within the source code and I have not changed the source code."_ Not gathering what you mean? Can you include the code that you adjusted at Question?

Comment: Do you mean that you modified files at directory https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/xmlhttprequest/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official instructions for debugging Chromium on Windows and specifically for setting breakpoints in renderer processes are here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows#TOC-Multi-process-issues.
Which of those steps have you tried?

Also, just to clarify: the JavaScript engine is V8, and it's in `<chromium>\src\v8`. It doesn't know anything about `XMLHttpRequest` because that's not an ECMAScript feature. The code in `<chromium>\src\third_party\WebKit\` is Blink, the HTML rendering engine. It contains the implementation of XHR (among many other things) and makes it available to JavaScript code via a layer called "bindings". (For setting breakpoints in renderer processes this distinction is irrelevant, as the procedure is always the same.)

Comment: Thanks!  That document gave me what I needed to get breakpoints working.  BTW, every so often Chromium crashes with an empty modal dialog box (the only content in the box is a glyph/icon, no text message), and in the browser I get the infamous "Aww, something went wrong" page with a Reload button.  Ever seen that.

Comment: I've seen and debugged lots of renderer crashes, but haven't seen any empty modal dialog boxes.

Comment: @jrmk Thanks.  If you happen to know what code module throws those boxes, let me know (assuming it's centrally located in the code).  In any case,  I appreciate the help.